# Does the Technician ability activate if a move's overall power is reduced due to battle type?

Tags: pokemon-series

So in doubles, I know that if a move that hits multiple Pokemon it has its power lowered to 75%. If a move has (for example) 75 base power, it will be lowered to about 56 base power.

Will, when the power is reduced, the [Technician bonus](https://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Technician_(Ability)) then trigger, or is the Technician ability triggered before the move hits multiple pokemon?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, Technician does not affect anything with a Base Power higher than 60. In a double battle, a move hitting multiple target has its damage lowered by 25%, but its Base Power is unchanged. Thus, Technician does not affect a move that would drop to an effective power of 60 or less due to the damage reduction in double battles.